# Error: Superclass has no method named 'desktopSignIn' in Firebase UI OAuth Google after running 'flutter pub outdated

Tags: flutter

When running flutter pub outdated on my Flutter application, which was working fine, I get the following error in the firebase_ui_oauth_google library:

```
../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_oauth_google-1.3.0/lib/src/provider.dart:97:13: Error: Superclass has no method named 'desktopSignIn'.
      super.desktopSignIn(action);
```

This error seems to indicate that the superclass does not have a method named 'desktopSignIn', leading to a halt in the application's execution. Prior to running flutter pub outdated, the application was working without any issues. I have not made any changes to the code related to Firebase authentication or to the Flutter configuration before this error occurred.

I have tried clearing the cache of libraries in my Flutter application to fix the error, but it hasn't worked. I have also tried changing or reverting the commits to a state where the application was working correctly, but it hasn't helped either. Does anyone know what else I can try to resolve this issue?

Comment: Same here with `firebase_ui_oauth_google: ^1.3.0`. Works fine on mobile, but not on web. Using `firebase_ui_oauth_google: 1.2.17` works too.

Answer (score 0):

Updating firebase_ui_oauth_google: ^1.3.0 to ^1.3.1 solved the issue for me. I had previously been at 1.2.5